# Why the setup function is not working in python

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools

I am running a program containing the setup function but the error:

```
 usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
 or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
 or: setup.py --help-commands
 or: setup.py cmd --help

 error: no commands supplied
```

is appearing.

I tried the command `python setup.py install` ( even with giving the path to supertools) but also i get:

```
python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What should  i do to solve this problem and be able to use the function setup.
Knowing that i am using `spyder anaconda` and the `python 3.6` version, and inside the `setuptools` package there is no file called `setup.py`

Comment: You must be trying to run it from the wrong directory.

Comment: Can you explain the steps you took to get to this issue? The normal flow is: download archive > decompress archive > "cd <package_name>" > "python setup.py install"

Comment: @Carcigenicate i chose the path to supertools from anaconda 3.

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, i just run a project containing the setup function. The normal flow to what you mean?

Comment: Please confirm whether this is your own project with a 'setup.py'? If so could you post the directory/folder structure?

Comment: @PaulaThomas no it's from phat package concerning homology computation. It's the setup that must be in supertools package and that is not contained in it in my case. I don't know if it's normal though

Comment: What is the name of the package?  Sorry, the package is called 'phat' isn't it? Stupid me!

Comment: How are you trying to install phat? I just did it using pip and it was distinctly weird - it appeared to fall over (loads of red lettering on screen - the last line of which complained about pybind11 missing and then installed anyway!!

Comment: Oh and are you sure the other package is called 'supertools' and not 'setuptools'?

Comment: @PaulaThomas i am installing phat using 'py -3.7 -m pip install phat' and i get this error command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2. And it's setuptools

Comment: OK a little puzzled why you are using pip to install when you said above that you are using anaconda, maybe the problem is there? Also puzzled as to why you said in the question that you have python 3.6 and appear to be installing a 3.7 compatible version of phat?

Comment: @Paula Thomas using pip and conda the problem is the same, it's 3.6 for conda and 3.7 for pip

Comment: Right. Hmmm can you try installing pybind11 specifically and then trying again? When I tried to install phat I got the equivalent error from gnu c (on linux) It appears that there is a dependency for pybind11 which is handled let's just say sub-optimally!

Comment: It's the same Paula, i think the problem is in setup.py since i get: Running setup.py install for phat ... error

Comment: Except we should be running the same setup.py! I'll have a think and get back,

Comment: @PaulaThomas Hello, any thoughts Paula?

Comment: Sorry, not one.